# Scripts that Rely on Docstrings?

Tags: python, compiler-optimization, removing-whitespace, docstring

From the 2.7.2 docs, Section 6, `Modules`:

`Passing two -O flags to the Python interpreter (-OO) will cause the bytecode compiler to perform optimizations that could in some rare cases result in malfunctioning programs. Currently only __doc__ strings are removed from the bytecode, resulting in more compact .pyo files.`

This got my attention:

`Since some programs may rely on having these available, you should only use this option if you know what you’re doing.`

Are there any cases where removing a script's docstrings might *logically* break some dependency or other aspect of a code's functionality, disregarding any syntactic errors?

## EDIT

Why would removing comments break a help statement? It doesnt seem to do so in the interpreter.

```
>>> help('import_pi')

Help on module import_pi:

NAME
    import_pi

FILE
    /home/droogans/py/import_pi.py

FUNCTIONS
    print_pi()

DATA
    pi = 3.1415926535897931


>>> import import_pi()
>>> import_pi.__doc__
>>>
>>> print import_pi.print_pi.__doc__
Convert a string or number to a floating point number, if possible.
```

Comment: Except for the part where docstrings are removed from the script. Or am I misreading both cases?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Yeah, no, `-OO` removes it from the byte code. It doesn't change your `.py` file, you are correct. I was simply relating the two because it was one of the few related questions on my subject. I normally write what led me to my question, and my thinking that got me there, since the first comment almost always goes something like: `more info please`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html) is a module that does lexing and parsing which uses docstrings to describe the grammar. Stripping docstrings would break the code.

Comment: +1 [The PLY parser](http://www.manaware.net/programming-techniques/lexyaccstyle-parsing-with-ply.html) follows a similar convention to the lexer in that for each BNF rule we create a function with the prefix p_, *and whose docstring contains the BNF rule we're matching* (only with ::= replaced with :)

Answer (score 1):

The `-OO` option only affects whether a doc string is stored -- it does not affect parsing.  For example the following code works with and without optimizations enabled:

```
def f():
    'Empty docstring'

assert f() is None
```

The programs that will break with the docstring optimization enabled are ones that rely on the **contents** of the docstring.  Paul Hankin mentioned Ply which is tool that uses docstrings for its dispatch logic.  Another example is the [doctest module](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#module-doctest) which uses the contents of docstrings for tests.

Here's a simple example of code that won't work with the `-OO` optimization enabled:

```
def f():
    '30 + 40'
    return eval(f.__doc__)

print f()
```

Note *help()* will still work with the `-OO` optimization enabled, but it will only find the function name, arguments, and module, but not the docstring:

```
>>> help(f)
Help on function f in module __main__:

f()
```

Comment: Mimicking your session here displayed the help for `f()` with the docstring `30 + 40` tabbed once on it's own line, printed below the function name. I am using python 2.6.

Comment: I take back my previous statement. You have assumed that the display of `help(f)` has taken place on a `.pyo` file. Apologies.